# How to specify default value for time for datetime-local input type?

Tags: html, datetime

I am new to HTML. I am stuck in a very simple problem. I am using [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)  input type in a web application.

```
<input type="datetime-local"/>
```

I just want to define a default value for the time field only. I know we can define default value as given below

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2017-06-01T08:30">
```

But the problem is that It defines the default value for both date & time. I want to define only for time input. Something like this

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="T08:30">
```

Can someone suggest how we can do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your date restricted at all or what would the default value for the date be? I don't think you can provide just a time value for these types of inputs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value

Comment: I suppose it would also depend on the backend you're using. Example: I use Python/Django, and if I wanted only the time, I'd run a function the get the `current_date_and_time`, then make a new object that formatted a string with the hours and seconds of the first object... Although it's much better to store it all as UTC, and convert everything to local time as needed.